What is the full word of clitic -ce?
Oxford Latin Dictionary says

-ce particle.  Deictic  particle,  usu.  enclitic  (cf,  Osc.  iuc, nom. sg, f. = ea); added to demonstratives and  in classical  L,
reduced  to  -c  (hic,  iliic;  hinc,  tunc); also ecce; proclitic in
cedo, cette.

So -ce is both enclitic and proclitic. As a clitic, it must be originated from a full word. What is the full word of -ce?

Can you give examples of other Latin clitics that come from full words? -que, -ne? That'd make it easier to understand what you're after.

It doesn't exist as a full word in Latin. It's only seen attached to other forms, either at the beginning (cedō) or at the end (ecce).
In some Indo-European languages it exists as an independent word, like Hittite kī "this", but that's not the case in Latin (or any Italic language for that matter).

Given that the question also mentions that it "must be originated from a full word", can you go into more detail regarding its pre-Italic origins? I think that would really make this answering (and whole thread) interesting.

@cmw I'm not really sure what that part of the question means. What's the full version of =que, for example?

It does indeed exist as a full word in Latin, so the full word of -ce is namely cis. I just looked up -ce and clicked into Proto-Indo-European *ḱe. It is strange that the other answer only knew about Hittite  (ki-i /⁠kī⁠/), when it's similar-sounding and on the same page—Proto-Indo-European/ḱís.
Other descendants where *ḱe is the head are citer, citimus, contra, and cum. Given the topic of cliticization, ecce and hic are relevant going into Late Latin. The rest of the descendants listed there are cedo and con-.

People tend to analyse PIE *ḱis as a compound including *ḱi or *ḱe, or as a secondary analogical formation from *ḱi. It's not really tenable to say that it's the full version of -ce in the sense that -ce is derived from it at any stage; you can't get the e vocalism from an original i (nor the o in con-).
